# Writing code to generate lattice in python

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have `N` particles and I want to place them in a 3D cuboidal lattice. I want to create a numpy array of shape `(N,3)` with the 3D locations of each point as a row of the array. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

If I have N particles, I would take the cube root of N, lets call it n. Taking the ceiling of n, I will make a lattice of size ceil(n)*ceil(n)*ceil(n) and start filling up the lattice with particles. Of course, since `(ceil(n))**3` is greater than `N`, I will have some empty spots, but that is fine.

I could make a for loop and add some if statements, but I was wondering if there was a way to make this more efficient using iterative tools or something.

Thank you in advance for any advice you have!

Answer (score 0):

I think I do not fully understand the question, but if you want to use loops and not broadcasting, and you want it to be fast ("efficient") you can try to use Numba to speed up the calculations.

http://numba.pydata.org/

As long as you work with simple data types, it should be able to JIT-compile efficient looping functions for you.